# C++ Boost.ASIO async_read_until slow

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm having an unusual issue.  I have a C++ Boost.ASIO web server, and to handle incoming requests I'm using this code:

```
boost::asio::async_read_until(
    socket_,
    response_,
    "\r\n\r\n",
    boost::bind(
            &connection::handle_read_headers,
            shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
    )
);
```

(where "socket_" is my boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket and "response_" is a boost::asio::streambuf)

I'm trying to just grab the headers of the request, then I later do a second async_read_until with transfer_exactly matching the "Content-Length" that was parsed from the request header.  The problem is that above code is taking 100-900ms to return on a very modern server (From that read block, until handle_read_headers() is called).  The incoming request looks like:

```
POST /load HTTP/1.1
host: www.mysite.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
From: googlebot(at)googlebot.com
Origin: http://www.mysite.com
Referer: http://www.mysite.com/another-page/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
X-Forwarded-For: 66.249.75.103
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Content-Length: 287
Connection: keep-alive

and-the-actual-content-is-here.... (287 bytes worth)
```

The headers seem to be terminated with a \r\n\r\n, and it does trigger the handle_read_headers() function before reading all the way to EOF (so it's not reading the whole page) - it actually is tripping the regex.  And these requests are coming from Google, so I'm quite confident it's not lag on their end.

Is there anything I could be overlooking on why it's taking so long to return?  Any other catches with aync_read_until I might have missed?

Thanks!

EDIT/UPDATE:
Okay, now I'm very confused.  In trying megabyte's suggestion, I switched from a streambuf to a character array (no luck), then I refactored my code to use async_read_some rather than async_read_until, and just scan for the delimited manually.  I also reset all OS variables (sysctrl.conf) to bone stock default (to narrow down possibilities).  Unfortunately I'm still seeing 100-900ms delays in the following code from calling handle_read() with the same incoming POST request:

```
socket_.async_read_some(
    boost::asio::buffer(response_),
    boost::bind(
        &connection::handle_read,
        shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
    )
);
```

where response_ is now:

```
boost::array<char, 4096> response_;
```

To no avail (same 100-900ms delays).  There's no way this is normal - any thoughts?

EDIT2:
Per the recommendation of Rhashimoto, I enabled handler tracking and found this oddity in the log:

```
[2013-07-05 15:58:39 - Thread 7fae57e3f700]: Incoming connection (0ms elapsed)
@asio|1373054319.874916|506*508|socket@0x7fae50004f98.async_receive
@asio|1373054319.874963|506*509|socket@0x7fffd40fed68.async_accept
@asio|1373054319.875008|<506|
@asio|1373054320.609088|>508|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=512
@asio|1373054320.609233|508*510|socket@0x7fae50004f98.async_receive
@asio|1373054320.609264|<508|
@asio|1373054320.609284|>510|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=404
[2013-07-05 15:58:40 - Thread 7fae57e3f700]: Received packet headers (638 bytes) - 734ms elapsed
```

There are over 700 milliseconds between the async_accept and async_receive.  In the code, it goes from this block (virtually straight from the "HTTP Server 2" of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html - server.cpp and connection.cpp):

```
new_connection_->start();
new_connection_.reset(new connection(
        io_service_pool_.get_io_service()
));
acceptor_.async_accept(
        new_connection_->socket(),
        boost::bind(
                &server::handle_accept,
                this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error
        )
);
```

and from the start() to:

```
void connection::start()
{
    boost::asio::async_read_until(
        socket_,
        response_,
        "\r\n\r\n",
        boost::bind(
            &connection::handle_read_headers,
            shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        )
    );
}
```

and when handle_read_headers() is called, 700ms have passed.

Does anyone have ANY ideas?  I'm completely lost.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm actually wondering if this could be caused by my socket object being busy somehow (or overloaded).  It's not within the OS, so perhaps it's in the middle of something else in my program.... is that possible?  And could that cause a lag spike on async_read_until?

Comment: And I'm heavily working with Keep-Alive connections - should I not call a socket shutdown after each request (or is that normal)?

Comment: First of all, do you use a performance profiler? What does it say?

Comment: A few ASIO versions ago, there was a [similar problem](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/2091), which cause was in `asio::streambuf`. A workaround is to use a fixed size buffer rather than `asio::streambuf`.

Comment: Megabyte, I tried switching to a character array, to no avail (updated original post with the new details).  Thanks though.  :(

Comment: Are you single-threaded?  I'm wondering if another task might be blocking your async read in the queue.  Can you post the [handler tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html) log?

Comment: How are you measuring the 100 to 900 millisecond delay?

Comment: Rhashimoto, it's a multi-threaded environment, very heavily based on the "HTTP Server 2" example at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_server_2 - and here is the handler tracking log: http://pastebin.com/7F22gFCz - the milliseconds I was quoting were from substracting two boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() snaps.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Here is a bit longer handler tracking log:  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fAUBT6PA
Thanks so much!

Comment: I just added an "EDIT2" to the original post, which adds more detail and code snippets around that final log I posted.

Comment: Using *@name* to [reply to a specific commenter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020) makes it more likely they will see it.  I suspect this problem is external to `boost::asio`.  Do you see the delay if you issue a request from the same host?  Alternatively (or in addition), you could try tracing packets, e.g. with `sudo tcpdump -i en0 tcp and port 80`, and see if there is a corresponding delay between handshake and data.

Comment: That's interesting... I ran this command "while [ 1 ]; do cat rawrequest.txt | nc localhost 80; done" and almost every response was 1 millisecond or less (an occasional spike, probably 1 in 50). So if it's external, are there any sysctl.conf settings on EC2 that could cause lag where I'm seeing it when hit with a high volume of requests (between 10 and 500 per second)?  Or what else should I look for?  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Check the latency on your server to/from outside hosts (e.g. with ping). I have heard of [latency issues on EC2 micro instances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9731864/1462337), though I have a long-running micro and my latencies seem fine. I guess it depends on whomever you're sharing the hardware with. Or maybe there's just something wrong with routing or traffic control to your particular instance (micro or not) - you could fire up a new one (in a different region, perhaps) and see if it behaves differently.  You might also ask over on serverfault.com - they have an `amazon-ec2` tag over there.

Comment: Unfortunately the ping seems fine, and I've tried many different instances, including some much larger types (c1.xlarge).  No luck.  I can't imagine I'm anywhere near saturating the NIC (a few dozen kilobytes per second max), and most of these packets are through a keep-alive connection.  I'm really at a loss...

Comment: I bet problem is inside `server::handle_accept`. Post this function body too.

Comment: Your longer handler tracking log has a number of "lost" receives, e.g. handler 15, 17, 19, 27, 29, 31, 36, 38, 43, etc. I don't see closes for those sockets, either - I wonder if they are just being left open.    There are a few `asio.misc:2` (EOF) receive errors in there, too, don't know if you expect that as it appears that you send data back anyway.  Besides investigating that, I would get a concurrent packet trace and attempt to match that up with the handlers in hopes of verifying that the delay is external. If it is and it isn't latency, then it's the remote host, Google notwithstanding.

Comment: Are you doing this work on a Mac? Try compiling with `-DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_KQUEUE` or `#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_KQUEUE 1`. If that works, it's because the implementation of kqueue(2) is pseudo-horked in that it has an artificial latency. By switching to `select(2)` and you should see an improvement. When you go in to production, be sure to re-enable kqueue(2) if you're running on FreeBSD. I see this problem with libevent(3), too, and after disabling kqueue(2) the problem vanishes. HTH.

Comment: @PSIAlt The sixth code block in my post (starting with new_connection_->start() is the entire contents of the handle accept function.  Sean, I'm running Amazon Linux (EC2), and I tried compiling with that flag, but I don't see any difference.  rhashimoto, I sometimes receive messy data (malformed headers) and hit an EOF, to which I send a bad request response.  I'm not clear on how I'd match up a packet trace - do you have at commands for me to run and get started with?  The socket is always closed - that portion of the log might be so busy the full connection lifecycle isn't included. Thanks!

Comment: @Harry well, what is `io_service_pool_` ?

Comment: @PSIAlt io_service_pool_ is an instantiation of the io_service_pool object defined here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server2/io_service_pool.hpp / .cpp

Comment: Capture packets with tcpdump, e.g. `tcpdump -i eth0 -w pfile` then copy the file locally to analyze with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Check if delays in the handler log match up with delays in the packet trace. If so (as I suspect) then your problem is not a programming issue.  Even boost can't make packets arrive faster :). Aside: if you get an EOF from a socket it generally means the other side closed the connection and any data you send back goes nowhere. Aside 2: those "lost" receives may be abandoned connections, not closed until timeout and more evidence of network issues.

Comment: Okay, after researching it quite a bit, it seems the lag is with the packet coming into the program (issues with the NIC or sockets?).  I've tested the network raw in both directions, and everything looks fine, plus connecting from localhost works great.  I'd guess the NIC was getting flooded, except it's happening at around 4-5 requests per second, and I'm aware other programs can handle far more than that (apache, nginx, etc).  Any idea what could cause the packets to lag like that under such a small load (happens from all hosts, with all requests after saturation)?

Comment: @Harry its more admin than programming issue, but directions are a)hardware issues(do not use cheap NICs on the server) b)server overload with packets per second c)memory overload(intensive swapping). To profile such things server statistics is needed(top, iostat etc)

Comment: It may be worth writing a small program to characterize the CPU behavior to get a general expected delay that results from context switching and being scheduled off from the physical processor.  Also, the `localhost` test is going to be skewed because when `nc` is running the instance is on the physical processor, and `localhost` will be handled by the OS with neither the physical layer nor the Xen driver domain affecting the results.

Comment: @PSIAlt I'm using c1.xlarge AWS EC2 instances for this with a gigabit NIC.  I'd expect that to be able to handle more than 10 request per second (at ~1k per request).  Something's just not adding up.  I feel like it's flooding the NIC (slow packet reception through boost), but there are so few connections it can't possibly...  Under load I run "netstat -tan | grep ':80 ' | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c" and receive: 
    346 ESTABLISHED
      1 LISTEN
      4 SYN_RECV
      7 TIME_WAIT

Comment: ... continuing:  So That shouldn't flood the network, even on a much slower connection.  I'm thinking it HAS to be code, because there's no way the hardware would choke on this little activity.  But the code is so straight-forward (accept, receive, send, close [unless keep-alive, when it goes back to re-read again]), I just have no idea.  The server is sitting 70% idle (via top), and lsof only shows 1-2k open file descriptors (not many at all).  Are there any other possibilities for this behavior?   =/  I'm really at a loss here...

Comment: I don't think you have eliminated the possibility that the delays are in the client.

Comment: You haven't provided any `tcpdump` data, so I am assuming you are not comfortable analyzing packet traces. If so, can you try implementing a simple socket application that just accepts the connection on the port, then reads the data synchronously? Do you see the same delay with this simple application?

Answer (score 4):

Lets look at the handlers log

```
[2013-07-05 15:58:39 - Thread 7fae57e3f700]: Incoming connection (0ms elapsed)
@asio|1373054319.874916|506*508|socket@0x7fae50004f98.async_receive
@asio|1373054319.874963|506*509|socket@0x7fffd40fed68.async_accept
@asio|1373054319.875008|<506|
@asio|1373054320.609088|>508|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=512
@asio|1373054320.609233|508*510|socket@0x7fae50004f98.async_receive
@asio|1373054320.609264|<508|
@asio|1373054320.609284|>510|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=404
[2013-07-05 15:58:40 - Thread 7fae57e3f700]: Received packet headers (638 bytes) - 734ms elapsed
```

From log we can see `async_receive` is called twice: first is called(#508) 734ms after handler setup(#506). Now, second `async_receive` is called(#510) 53 microseconds after handler setup(#508). Thats it, second handler call was fired blasingly fast because the data (those 404 bytes) was already ready in TCP stack.

**Conclusion**: it is not a handler call delay, it is transport delay. Probably trouble with the ISP or a balancer, or maybe Google really dont want to bother you with requests and setting up delays.

UPD: I think you can check this with `tcpdump`

P.S. I dont like `io_service_pool_` implementation from HTTP server 2 example. This can cause some problems too, but i think its not current case.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a comment to the main post explaining my further research down this direction.  And regarding the PS, what about the io_service_pool implementation?  Do you recommend a different design for better performance?  That's an area outside the scope of this question, but I'd REALLY appreciate some insight into.  Thanks!

Comment: @Harry answered the comment at the top. Seems really delay issue is not related to software. About io_service pool its long story but in short: if one instance of `io_service` gets overloaded (or executing long working job) - all handlers in this instance will wait and blocked, since there is only 1 thread per `io_service` by design. I prefer to run 1 `io_service` and a thread pool serving its handlers.