# c++, boost asio, slow read

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have slightly modified client code taken from this [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp). The problem I'm having right now is that boost:asio:read call reads **really** slow, somewhere about 2 bytes per second.

`while (boost::asio::read(socket, response, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error));`

or

`boost::asio::read(socket, response, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);`

[Entire code here](http://pastebin.com/SpGBtAmA)

I've tried to get a response from different servers, including google.com, got same result, so its neither a server issue nor connection issue. Am I doing something wrong?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

Might be related: [C++ Boost.ASIO async_read_until slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478230/c-boost-asio-async-read-until-slow)

Comment: have you tried enabling [handler tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html)? What network transport are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The read is not slow, you just forgot to specify the close header:

```
    request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n";
```

This makes the process swift.

Note that the debug output wasn't 'instantaneous' due to buffering, try

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);
```